# I am not being able to change from gym to gymnasium

Tags: openai-gym, dqn

I am trying to test a code done with Gym but I am having lot of warnings.
The code is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/GiannisMitr/DQN-Atari-Breakout/blob/master/dqn_atari_breakout.ipynb#scrollTo=UFF_-bxm0UAB):
But I have changed things and I have it like this [right now:](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AwtS7lfKnY76pP28Eg_evDMv9CfYMOBn?usp=sharing)

Right now I am able to charge the enviroment with `gym.make` but when I call `env.reset()` it says me that:

```py
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-a310f9d722d7> in <cell line: 9>()
 7    
 8 env = make_env()   
 ----> 9 env.reset()   
 10 n_actions = env.action_space.n    
 11 state_dim = env.observation_space.shape   

 2 frames  
 <ipython-input-5-d1aed280949f> in observation(self, img) 
 17 
 18         # crop image (top and bottom, top from 34, bottom remove last  16) 
---> 19     img = img[34:-16, :, :]  
 20 
 21         # resize image 


TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

And I do not understand why.
If someone can help I would be very pleased.
Thanks

I expected it to work because I am using the same enviroment as in the main code, but I do not know what is happening with `env.reset()`. I am not a programmer, I am only a student and I have been trying for so long with that.

Answer (score 0):

`env.reset()` calls the reset function of the environment. You could see this as a new world being generated, where the environment applies the initial state distribution to make the first observation in the new environment. This is also exactly what is returned when calling `env.reset()`: it returns a tuple of the form `(observation, info)`. Observation will show you the starting state or a specific observation used in the environment. Info often gives you additional information about factors in the environment, such as velocity.

What you should do is save the observation of the environment in a variable and then call `env.step()`. Keep in mind when you just want the observation, to call

```py
observation, _ = env.reset()
```

Furthermore, StackOverflow questions must be self-contained: you will want your code posted in this thread instead of a link to a Google Colab.

Comment: Thank you, but i continue with problems. Thing is a want to configure the enviroment to work as it worked with Gym, but using the new Api explained here, https://gymnasium.farama.org/content/migration-guide/ But i am not being able.
I am going to let you the original code and let see if you can help me.